# Programmatically enable the entity view display

Tags: 9, layout-builder

I would like to programmatically enable the Layout Builder module. I  followed the instructions given on [Layout Builder — building Drupal 8 layouts](https://www.droptica.com/blog/layout-builder-building-drupal-8-layouts/), but they don't seem to work. They might be outdated for Drupal 9.1. Specifically, I'm having a hard time getting the following piece of code to work.

```php
$entityViewDisplay = \Drupal::entityTypeManager->getStorage('entity_view_display')
  ->load('ENTITY_TYPE.ENTITY_BUNDLE.VIEW_MODE');
```

Can anyone help me understand it? I just keep getting a `NULL` result.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. You can enable Layout Builder by running the following code in a custom module:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$content_type = 'article';
$view_type = 'default';

\Drupal\layout_builder\Entity\LayoutBuilderEntityViewDisplay::load("{$entity_type}.{$content_type}.{$view_type}")
  ->enableLayoutBuilder()
  ->setOverridable()
  ->save();
```

Hopefully this helps someone else. Having to do it via the UI is painful if you have a lot of content types. I'm actually surprised this isn't a Drush command yet. Oh well.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3158916